# Exporting as obj and texture problem

Tags: texturing, objects, export

I exported y design as obj file. Here is the render view. Then when I try to run my obj file in another program ( Vizard), its dark and looks horrible. I attached the screen shot. What am I doing wrong?[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience has been that exporting objects between programs is a huge pain, especially exporting obj's and expecting the texture to remain intact. I would suggest rebuilding the texture in the program you are exporting it to, as exporting the mesh is fine but exporting a uv map texture can be sort of a bother.